# What does $sup\{|f_1(x)-f(x)|, x \in D\}$ exactly mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I think it means the maximal distance between $f1$ and $f$ when you try all $x's$, I mean you test the distance between $f1$ and $f$, for all $x's$ and then you pick the max aka the supremum. Is this right?

Comment: Do you mean $f_1$ or $f_n$?

Comment: yes, I corrected it

Comment: In that case, yes - it means you take the supremum of the distances between $f(x)$ and $f_1(x)$. Important to note that the supremum always exists (possibly infinity), whereas the maximum may not.

Comment: In the case of real valued functions of one real variable, this can be visualized as the maximum (or supremum, when the maximum doesn't exist) **VERTICAL** separation between the graphs of the two functions when the $x$-coordinates are restricted to be in the set $D.$ **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)**  Equivalently, imagine drawing a vertical line at each $x \in D.$ Each of these vertical lines intersects each graph at exactly one point (vertical line test for functions), so you get two intersection points (the points might be coincident) for each vertical line. Now take the maximum (or supremum, when the maximum doesn't exist) of the separation distances for all these pairs of intersection points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you're right. The supremum (as you seem to have got down) is like the max, except it doesn't need to be in the set.

For example,

$$\sup{(\{\frac{x}{x+1} \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\})} = 1$$

but $1$ is not in that set.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering :)

Comment: The set in question is bounded from above. A supremum is its least upper bound.